# Array does not hold value in Spinner for android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I'm having a problem where the String array does not hold the value. I declare the array global like this.

> String[] temp;

And I initialize the value in a method where different values for spinner will hold the different values of temp. The code is like this:

```
public void pilih(){

    choose.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_calorie)"};
                    break;

                case 1:
                    temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_carbs)"};
                    break;

                case 2:
                    temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_protein)"};

                    break;

                case 3:
                    temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_fat)"};

                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

Then, I called the method above in another method.

```
public ArrayList<Entry> getDataValues() {

    pilih();

    ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor;

    cursor = db.query("meal", temp, null, null, "meal_date", null, "meal_date desc");

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        date = cursor.getString(1);// get final total
        dataVals.add(new Entry(i, cursor.getFloat(1)));
    }

    return dataVals;
}
```

And I called the getDataValues() to display the data in SQLiteDatabase. However, it seems like the temp array does not hold the initialize value. I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong. But, can you help me?

Comment: You should not call that method pilih() like that ... that method will just set the setOnItemSelectedListener onto spinner ...you have to get the selected value from spinner instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign array like this ...Replace your pillih() with this

```
 public void pilih()
    {  
        int position=choose.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_calorie)"};
                break;

            case 1:
                temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_carbs)"};
                break;

            case 2:
                temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_protein)"};

                break;

            case 3:
                temp = new String[]{"meal_date", "sum(tot_fat)"};

                break;

        }

    }
```

The method that you wrote will just set the setOnItemSelectedListener onto spinner ...you have to get the selected value from spinner instead